# What is the official name for the "additional readings" on special torah-reading days?

Tags: words, hebrew, torah-reading, parsha-torah-portion

On certain special Shabboses, like the four parshiyot, there is a special torah reading that replaces Maftir after the weekly parsha is read.  Is there a name for this extra not-from-the-weekly-parsha Maftir reading?

Comment: By the way, I think it might be "maftirs." Source: "There are also special maftirs ('additional Torah readings') " from here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_Shabbat#Shabbat_Chol_HaMoed

Comment: "Maftir" is the term used for the portion of the Torah read by the person who will soon read the Haftara (and also for the person himself). It is not unique to those weeks where the Maftir is not just the end of the standard reading.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm aware of that definition of "maftir."

Comment: Are you looking for a category name for the additions to the torah reading, for example on Zachor we read the regular parsha and add the verses about Amalek?  (Those are read as part of the torah reading, not after the haftarah.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio Yes! And thanks, you're right. (BTW, are the "additional readings" read as part of Maftir? or in the aliyah before?)

Comment: @SAH the special readings are *maftir* in those cases.  On "three-scroll" days (like if Rosh Chodesh in Chanukah is on Shabbat) things get more complicated.

Comment: @SAH I've made an edit to clarify the question based on your comments.  If I've misunderstood please feel free to roll back or edit further.  Thanks.

Comment: As stated in the above comments, they are simply considered Maftir. They are not "additional", as you state in your question title, but, rather, substitutions for the regular parsha's maftir. Thus, it maintains the status of "maftir" and, I believe that's exactly what it's called. In some cases, it is called "Maftir Zachor" or something similar (some call it that), but, it still maintains the name "maftir".

Comment: I assume that you are asking specifically about maftir and not haftarah. There are a few situations where the haftarah is not the normal parsha's haftarah, yet the maftir is the regular Shabbat parsha's maftir. (Shabbat Hagadol is one example.)

Comment: @DanF OK, now I'm really confused. Isn't Maftir usually (mostly) Haftarah? So are you saying that the ~additional readings replace the haftarah??

Comment: @SAH maftir is the final aliya in the torah reading.  Most weeks it's a repetition of the last few verses of the seventh aliya, but on these special Shabbatot we read something else instead (usually from a different scroll).  Either way, it's then followed by a haftarah reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be confused regarding the term "maftir" and how it works.

"Maftir" refers to the "additional" aliyah that occurs after the other 7 required aliyot on Shabbat. There is always a maftir, so there is no **additional** maftir. It is merely that one maftir is substituted in place of the standard weekly maftir.

Some people call the Haftarah "maftir". The word "maftir" refers to the last reading from the Torah, whereas "haftarah" refers to the reading from the prophets. The person who reads the haftarah receives the maftir aliyah.

On mincha of fast days and Tish'a B'av morning, the "maftir" aliyah is not an extra one, but rather is the 3rd aliyah. That's the only exception to not adding an extra one as we have on Shabbat and Yom Tov.

Sometimes you hear someone say "I have maftir Yonah" if he is reading that section on Yom Kippur afternoon. That's become parlance, I suppose, but as I explained above, he should say, "I have haftarah Yonah".

Comment: 'Maftir' is just a verb of the same root as 'Haftarah'. It means "[the one who] performs-the-Haftara". The Maftir Aliya is the Aliya receieved by the Maftir, that is, the performer-of-the-Haftarah. Just like the Magbiah is the performer-of-Hagbah. 'Maftir' has nothing to do with "extra" (any less than 'Haftarah' does).

Comment: Thank you for this "some people call the haftarah 'maftir'" -- I think this was one source of the (my?) confusion

Comment: I don't think anybody calls the haftarah "maftir". "Maftir Yonah" is a colloquial name for the combined honor of having the maftir aliya and reading sefer Yonah as the haftarah. Sometimes there is indeed more than one additional reading (e.g. Shabbos Rosh Chodesh Teves or when Parshas HaChodesh falls on Rosh Chodesh Nissan)

Answer (score 4):

I have never heard of a name that refers specifically to the category of "*maftir* readings that are not from the weekly *sedra*," and I do not believe that such a name exists. In my experience, such a reading is usually just referred to as a "special *maftir* reading" (as you mentioned in [your comment](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67654/what-is-the-official-name-for-the-additional-readings-on-special-torah-reading#comment191273_67654)).

---

## Addendum

I will try to clarify some of the confusion that has appeared in the comments on this post and answers about the word "*maftir*". The *maftir* is the person who reads the *haftarah*. Both words come from the same root (פ.ט.ר.‏). *Maftir* is the present-tense third-person form of the word in *binyan Hif'il*. I don't want to get too deep into a grammar lesson, but *Binyan Hif'il* is used for causative verbs (i.e. performing an action). The third-person present-tense *hif'il* verb form is also often used to refer to a person who performs that action, so that's why the person who reads the *haftarah* is called the *maftir*.

The *maftir* is given the *aliya* before the *haftarah*. That *aliya* is therefore called the *maftir aliya* (which is sometimes abbreviated as simply *maftir*). Most *Shabbatot*, the *maftir aliya* is simply a repeat of the last few verses from that week's *sedra*; however, on certain special *Shabbatot* (e.g. the Four *Parshiot*) as well as holidays there is a "special *maftir*" from a completely different part of the Torah. That is the reading that your quesiton asks about and for which I do not believe there is any special name.

Comment: So the maftir reads both the maftir aliya (=repeated verses, or special stuff) and the haftarah after?  Are these considered separate aliyot? Does he come up twice?  (PSA: women's sections need to be better designed)

Comment: @SAH he doesn't necessarily read from the Torah aloud during the _maftir aliya_. He is just called up for the _aliya_ (says the _berakhot_ and reads along quietly with the Torah reader, like any other _aliya_). He usually just stays up there during the _hagbaha_ and then reads the _haftarah_. He is only called up by name once.